# How to undo add selection in sublime text3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I usually `ctrl+left click` to add a new cursor to edit multilines.

But how can I undo a cursor when I made a wrong selection?

Answer (score 2):

The `Soft Undo` function is what you want here.

It's in the menu as `Edit > Undo Selection > Soft Undo`, along with an associated option to redo as well.

If you check the menu, it will tell you what the key binding for your platform is set to by default. For example, on Windows it's <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
But I remember I could use `ctrl + left click` to substract a cursor. Now it doesn't work any more. It's so wired.